# rabbitmq-server issue while installing in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS(focal)

Tags: 20.04, rabbitmq

I am trying to install rabbitmq-server in my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS(focal) I am following the steps while installing it :

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

All steps are working fine except when I try to install it finally by typing `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`  few moments later it raise error given below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.9.7-1) ...
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-09-29 22:54:48 +06; 6ms ago
    Process: 18045 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 18045 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Standing by"
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Please tell me what's going wrong and how can I solve it ?Help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: The system is trying to tell you what's wrong. Perform the steps in the line starting with "`See `".

Comment: Seen that .. doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment above, you should enter the following to see the specific error(s):

```sh
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
```

and

```sh
sudo journalctl -xe
```

This should say what configuration caused the service to fail to start.